# Proper way to listen for lo-level events in extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a extension for Visual Studio Code and I am wondering what is the proper way to listen for events like KeyDown, KeyUp, MoseDown, etc. I need access to those so that I can count key presses and other metrics.

I saw that ViewController(vscode/src/vs/editor/browser/view/viewController.ts) emits the exact events that I am interested in to its events bus. Is there a way to subscibe to those events, and more importantly what is the proper way to do that.

Thank you.